# Relation of Laravel 4 Eloquent not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am setting up two Models. Let's assume we have a portfolio and portfolio_category table

**Table portfolio**

```
id
cat_id
name
status
```

**Table portfolio_category**

```
cat_id
cat_name
```

**Model**

```
class Portfolio extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];   
    public function portfolio_category() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Portfolio_category');
    }
}

class Portfolio_category extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    public function portfolio() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Portfolio');
    }
}
```

**My code:**

```
$data = Portfolio::all();
foreach($data as $value){
    $id = $value['id'];
    $name = $value['name'];
    $cat_name = $value['cat_name'];
}
```

I want to display category name but it shows null values.

I am pretty confused, what went wrong? any idea!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer

```
$data = Portfolio::join('portfolio_category', 'portfolio_category.cat_id', '=', 'portfolio.cat_id')->get();
foreach($data as $value){
    $id = $value['id'];
    $name = $value['name'];
    $cat_name = $value['cat_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are not defined correctly. In your code, you've tried to define the Portfolio as the parent, and the Portfolio_category as the child. However, your tables are setup such that the Portfolio_category is the parent and the Portfolio is the child. Basically, the table that contains the foreign key (portfolio table has foreign key to portfolio_category) should be on the belongsTo side.

So, instead of portfolio hasMany portfolio_category and portfolio_category belongsTo portfolio, it needs to be switched to portfolio_category hasMany portfolio and portfolio belongsTo portfolio_category.

Additionally, I'm assuming these were removed for brevity, but the table names and the primary key on your portfolio_category table do not conform to Laravel conventions, so you need to specify these properties in the model.

Your models should look like:

```
class Portfolio extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'portfolio';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function portfolio_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Portfolio_category');
    }
}

class Portfolio_category extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'portfolio_category';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function portfolios() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Portfolio');
    }
}
```

Now you can access the related tables through the relationships:

```
$data = Portfolio::with('portfolio_category')->get();
foreach($data as $value){
    $id = $value->id;
    $name = $value->name;
    $cat_name = $value->portfolio_category->cat_name;
}
```

For more on the Eloquent ORM, the documentation can be found [here (L4.2)](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) or [here (L5.0)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent).

Comment: I have used your code but it gave me some error when I used $value->portfolio_category->cat_name; Error is: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @okconfused Assuming the relationships are setup correctly, that would mean that you have a Portfolio that doesn't have a related Portfolio_category.  In that case, `$value->portfolio_category` would be NULL (since one doesn't exist), and you'd get that error.  Try `$cat_name = $value->portfolio_category ? $value->portfolio_category->cat_name : '';`

Comment: Portfolio have related portfolio_category in the db but still error display which i have told you in previous comment.

Comment: @okconfused Did you update the `$cat_name` assignment as I mentioned in my comment?  You may need to update your question with the current version of your code.

Comment: My update code is:
$data = Portfolio::with('portfolio_category')->get();
foreach($data as $value){
    $id = $value->id;
    $name = $value->name;
    $cat_name = $value->portfolio_category ? $value->portfolio_category->cat_name : '';
}

$cat_name shows null

Comment: @okconfused What does `$data = Portfolio::with('portfolio_category')->get(); var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());` show?

Comment: It shows three array with these data: array[1]:  [query] => select * from `od_users` where `od_users`.`user_id` = ? limit 1, array[1]: [query] => select * from `od_portfolio`, array[2]: [query] => select * from `od_portfolio_category` where `od_portfolio_category`.`portfolio_category_id` in (?)